# Creating a new file for new view in swift

Tags: swift

How can i create a .swift for my newly created view in mainstoryboard. I want to control drag my labels in my new view, but nothing happens. Anybody has solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create an empty `.swift` file. Then, make it a subclass of `UIView`, e.g.

```
import UIKit

class MyView : UIView
{
}
```

Finally, in the `.xib` of the view, set the new class as custom class. After this you can drag connections between the XIB and the class.

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: I actually managed it. Tried to edit my comment. Everything is awesome now! You inspired me man!